# Como resolver uma falha de segmetação em C com vetores?

Tags: c

Oie! Não estou sabendo o que está dando errado.  Quando eu compilo no codeblock meu codigo, dá tudo certo. Entretanto quando enviei o codigo para a avaliação no run codes, eles retornaram que além de demorar muito ele está dando Falha de Segmentação. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   int fib[60], N;

   scanf("%d", &N);

   int ent[N];
   fib[0] = 0;
   fib[1] = 1;

   for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
     scanf("%d", &ent[i]);

   for(int j=2; j < 60; j++)
    fib[j] = fib[j-1] + fib[j-2];


    for(int k=0; k < 60; k++)
    printf("Fib(%d) = %d\n", ent[k], fib[ent[k]]);

    return 0;
}
```

Meu intuito com esse codigo é fazer que quando a pessoa digitar um numero N, apareça N espaços para ela preencher que serão a posição da sequencia de Fibonacci de forma que ficará:

Entrada: 
3 
2 
3 
6

Saida:  
Fib(2) = 1 
Fib(3) = 2 
Fib(6) = 8

Espero que tenha dado para entender...

Comment: O último laço é para percorrer `ent` que tem tamanho `N` e não 60 como está codificado.

Comment: Para esse tipo de falhas de segmentação o ideal é usar a ferramenta valgrind ou similar. Essa consegue lhe dar uma ideia de em que local no código está o problema. De qualquer form ao @Maniero já indicou qual o problema no seu código.

Comment: Obrigado Galera. Vocês me ajudaram muito!!